# Property 'publish' does not exists on type Observable<string> in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I'm writing my first `Angular` application in `Angular 6`.

I'm implementing **Error Handling** to handle all errors in a single place and for that, I'm following [this Medium guide](https://medium.com/@aleixsuau/error-handling-angular-859d529fa53a)

According to the guide code sample [here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/error-handling-in-angular-step2-gu4hyo), my **NotificationService** is like

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {publish} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  private _notification: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  readonly notification$: Observable<string> = this._notification.asObservable().publish().refCount();

  constructor() {}

  notify(message) {
    this._notification.next(message);
    setTimeout(() => this._notification.next(null), 5000);
  }
}
```

and the IDE is giving an error at `publish()`

[image]

I have even imported `publish` from `rxjs/operators` but import is showing unused. I also tried import as in guide sample, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `publish` function no longer exists on the `Observable`, you need to use it with pipe, like so:

```
import { publish, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';  

//...

private _notification: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
readonly notification$: Observable<string> = this._notification.asObservable().pipe(
      publish(),
      refCount()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `publish` and `refCount`, you may be interested in the `share()` function which performs both. This was introduced due to the popularity of the pattern (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/16/cold-vs-hot-observables.html) . As described by user184994, but with a small modification:

```
import { publish, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';  

//...

private _notification: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
readonly notification$: Observable<string> = this._notification.asObservable().pipe(
      share()
)
```